# flutter- Regex: split text that started with @

Tags: regex, flutter

I my trying to write regex on my flutter application.  I have this text:

`@rtt tty tr@fh @rggg`

I  want to just split `@rtt , @rggg` so I add this regex pattern: `^@(\S+)`.

But this pattern just split first matches: `@rtt`. https://regex101.com/r/p2K9Yy/1

How can I write a pattern to split all matches ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\S)@(\S+)
\B@(\S+)
```

The `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind requires either start of string or a whitespace immediately to the left of the current location, and `\B` before `@` requires either start of string or a non-word char to appear immediately before.

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/zf2LMa/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/zf2LMa/2).

In Dart, you can use

```dart
String x ="@rtt tty tr@fh @rggg";
RegExp rx = new RegExp(r'\B@(\S+)');
var values = rx.allMatches(x).map((z) => z.group(1)).toList();
print(values); // => [rtt, rggg]
  
var values2 = rx.allMatches(x).map((z) => z.group(0)).toList();
print(values2); // => [@rtt, @rggg]
```